# How to setup the correct indexes in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I'm using partitioning `RANGE BY(person_id)` (10 users per sub-table) and I have these `PRIMARY` keys:
`id`,
`person_id`. `id` is a `UNIQUE` and auto-increment index. These indexes are holding articles that were written by `person_id`. If I want to retrieve all articles that were written by, lets say, `person_id` = 748172, I can run this query: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE person_id = 748172`. But what I want to achieve, is that to be able to get older articles by running this query: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE person_id = 748172 AND id < 472785478 (or older...)`. Should I use composite index `ALTER TABLE articles ADD INDEX '...' (person_id, id)` for this case? The design of this table will be used to have up to 1 billion rows. Performance is very important here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be going with NON-Clustered index when have large number of rows and performance is critical.

Comment: as far as I know, the PRIMARY KEY is a clustered index. All other indexes are non-clustered by default.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. 
Clustered index enforces the order of rows in the table. But here case is different, you wish to have older and older records to show up so you can enable non-clustered index over person_id and clustered index we already have with id.

Comment: So adding a non-clustered index to `person_id` will be enough?

Comment: I think it should be fine!
Here is how it will work:
First for non-clustered index, database will go to the person_id index and look for the address of the corresponding rows in the table, it will then go to that row address and fetch other column values. And once non-clustered set is ready then  rows will be visible as per id(clustered index) order.